# Creation of URL in function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to build URL in a function and then click it on html page.

How I want to build URL:

```
        scope.sendChooosenDeviceToController = function (choosenDevice) {
            scope.choosenDevice = choosenDevice;

            createRouteUrl(choosenDevice);

            function createRouteUrl(choosenDevice){
                var longitude = choosenDevice.coords.longitude;
                var latitude = choosenDevice.coords.latitude;
                var routeUrl = 'https://maps.google.com?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=' + latitude +',' + longitude;
                console.log('TEEN::',routeUrl);
                return routeUrl
            };
        }
```

and html:

```
<a ng-href="{{deviceUrl.value}}" target="_blank">
    <button class="btn-blue">Route to</button>
</a>
```

Solution does not work, how to implement it ?

Thanks !

Comment: where do you set the deviceUrl.value?

Comment: From what i see, your function is in JS, why do you try displaying a twig variable ? (if i'm not wrong on the syntax).

Comment: @L.Dia Just deviceUrl also does not work ;/

Comment: Don't mind my comment on twig, but i have the same question than Fribu in your code i saw no deviceUrl var ...

Comment: Stupid error, I am exhausted. Thanks!